# MySQL Workbench: How can I see the detailed SQL query and errors when I use the "Apply" button? (confirmation popup)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I recently upgraded from MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 up to 6.1.

After making changes to a table via the Gui grid interface on the old version, I'd hit the 'Apply' button and have a popup confirming to make the change.  This popup had the SQL code that would run in order to make the change that I made via the UI interface.  I would then confirm the action and get a success or failure popup.  If a an error occurred, I could see the detailed error in order to easily troubleshoot the problem.

With the new version, I make a change in the GUI interface and hit the 'Apply' button.  No confirmation popup, it just executes.  The result is a small snippet in output window.  This is fine unless there's an error, in which case it has a very generic message. "1 error(s) saving changes to table XYZ".  I have not found how to access the detailed error message, either by right clicking the row or looking in the preferences.

So, how do I get the popup confirmation with SQL query and error messaging to work in the new version or, at the very least, be able to see detailed SQL query error details?

Comment: The documentation says to check the 'confirm data changes' checkbox for the 'wizard' (pop up) to appear.  This is checked in my preferences but no wizard/confirmation appears.  Possibly a bug?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bug :-(

In the MySQL bug database:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72169

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72155

Answer (score 2):

Functionality restored in CE release: 6.1.7

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=452662

Answer (score 1):

Until they don't fix the bug you can try to close the Query Tab. When it asks if you want Save the Changes or Not, you choose Save and then it shows the detailed errors :)